# Memory leak using Mongo with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have found a pretty severe memory leak in my application.  When trying to bulk write into Mongo, using Morphia, performance dips swiftly, and continues to degrade. (i.e. initial 100 records take < 1 second to write, records 8899 to 9000 take 310 seconds.)

Using Yourkit I can see than com.mongodb.BasicDBObject, com.mongodb.DBRef, com.mongodb.BasicDBList have very high retained sizes (41-81%) and continually report as Pending Finalisation.

Additionally, if I change datastore.save(...) to write to disk instead, I do not see the performance degradation.

I am not using MongoOptions at the moment.  Should I be?  What tweaks are available to improve the performance of my application?

I am using mongo java driver version 2.7.0, and morphia 0.99.1-SNAPSHOT.

I call my controller method in a simple for loop:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reports", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public ResponseEntity<Result> add(@RequestParam("title") String title,
                                                   @RequestParam("uri") String uri,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "imageUri", required = false) String imageUri,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "categoryIds", required = false) List<String> categoryIds,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "expertsIds", required = false) List<String> expertIds,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "userId", required = false) String userIdString,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "description", required = false) String description) {

    if (imageUri == null) {
        imageUri = "";
    }

    List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    if (categoryIds != null && !categoryIds.isEmpty()) {
        categories = categoryService.getCategoriesById(categoryIds);
    }

    Report report = new Report(StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(title), uri, imageUri, categories, expertIds, description);

    UUID userID = userService.convertUserId(userIdString);
    Result result = userService.addReport(userID, report);

    return new ResponseEntity<Result>(result);
}

 public Result addReport(UUID userID, Report report) {
    Result result = reportService.add(report);
    if (!result.getErrorMessages().isEmpty()) {
        return result;
    }
    if (!doesUserExistInDb(userID)) {
        createUserWithId(userID);
    }
    updateUserWithReport(userID, report);
    return result;
}

public Result add(Report report) {
    Result result = new Result();
    try {
        datastore.save(report);
        result.addReport(report);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException ex) {
        populateValidationErrors(result, ex);
    }
    return result;
}

public void updateUserWithReport(UUID userID, Report report) {
    User user = datastore.get(User.class, userID);
    user.getReports().add(report);
    datastore.save(user);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample code for your "bulk writes", or an example showing the slow-down?

Comment: Where is the "bulk" part? I only see single "save" calls made. It looks like from this code you cannot use "bulk inserts" since you need to update individual Entities.

Comment: I simply call the api method in a simple for loop - with data populated from a spreadsheet.

Comment: Please show the code that works, and the code which causes problems.